# Why isn't my UIMenuController shown in my view?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I can't figure out why my UIMenuController doesn't show up in my view.
When I long-press the button, I can see that all instructions are executed, but menu is not shown.

```
public class MySingleArticleView : UIView
{
    private MyArticleViewController _controller; // MyArticleViewController extends BaseViewController

    public MySingleArticleView (MyArticleViewController controller, ...)
    {
        _controller = controller;

        // ... init code
    }

    void ArticleLongPressed (UILongPressGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
    {
        var menuController = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;
        var copyMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("copy", new Selector ("CopyRow"));
        var pasteMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("paste", new Selector ("PasteRow"));
        var location = gestureRecognizer.LocationInView (_controller.View);
        _controller.BecomeFirstResponder ();
        menuController.MenuItems = new [] { copyMenuItem, pasteMenuItem };
        menuController.SetTargetRect (new CGRect (location.X, location.Y, 0, 0), _controller.View);
        menuController.SetMenuVisible (true, true);
    }

    [Export("CopyRow")]
    void Row (UIMenuController controller)
    {
        // do something
    }

    [Export("PasteRow")]
    void PasteRow (UIMenuController controller)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself and maybe someone else can have the same problem.

I needed to put colon ':' after the exported function name, so:

```
[Export("PasteRow:")] 
void PasteRow (UIMenuController controller) 
{ 

}

[Export("CopyRow:")] 
void CopyRow (UIMenuController controller) 
{ 

}
```

Similarly, when instatiating:

```
var copyMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("copy", new Selector ("CopyRow:")); 
var pasteMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("paste", new Selector ("PasteRow:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are providing a height and width value equal to 0 when you set the target rect:

```
menuController.SetTargetRect (new CGRect (location.X, location.Y, 0, 0), _controller.View);
```

Try giving it a height and width and see if it shows up:

```
menuController.SetTargetRect (new CGRect (location.X, location.Y, 100, 100), _controller.View);
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, but even specifying other values, the menu controller still doesn't display. However, 0 0 was set following an example on Xamarin website: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIMenuController/

Comment: @D.Morresi Did you find solution? I'm struggling with the same issue...

Comment: @Mariusz yes, it seems that it didn't like the way I declared Export command and functions... I changed it in: `[Export("PasteRow:")] void PasteRow (UIMenuController) { }` and `[Export("CopyRow:")] void CopyRow (UIMenuController) { }`. Then, I changed the part above with: `var copyMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("copy", new Selector ("CopyRow:"));` `var pasteMenuItem = new UIMenuItem ("paste", new Selector ("PasteRow:"));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you saved a lot of my time :)